# Implementing double-click event for ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've seen plenty of examples of how to add a double-click event for each ListView item, but I can't figure out how to implement it to my code. The best example I found so far is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-handle-the-mousedoubleclick-event-for-each-item-in-a-listview) one in MS docs, but it still doesn't help me handle this :

```
<ListView Name="listViewItem" ClipToBounds="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Margin="0,0,117,0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Task ID" Width="0">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskID}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Tast Title" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskTitle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Task Deadline" Width="275">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskDeadline}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Task Group" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskGroup}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Task Contact" Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskContact}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Task Workers" Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskWorkers}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I have a helpers class that sets values on load event ->

```
public void GetGridTasks(ref ListView listViewItem)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommandRefresh = new SqlCommand("", dataconnection);

            sqlCommandRefresh.CommandText = "SELECT TaskID, TaskTitle, TaskDeadline, TaskGroup, TaskContact, TaskWorkers FROM Tasks";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommandRefresh);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tasks");
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                dr["TaskWorkers"] = dr["TaskWorkers"].ToString().Replace("||", ", ");
            }

            listViewItem.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
```

This is basically TextBlocks inside GridView inside ListView. Can't really wrap my head around fixing this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the MouseDoubleClick Event from the ListView.

Example:

```
<ListView MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
//Items here
</ListView>
```

In your code behind you simply add an event handler for that

```
void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    var item = ((FrameworkElement) e.OriginalSource).DataContext
    var myItem = item as *CastToWhateverTypeYouNeed*
    if (item != null){
        //Here you have your item
    }
}
```

Comment: That event fires when I click on a column or empty areas which just won't do. I only need this to activate when you click on a list item, I'll need to get values from it later.

Comment: I tried setting myItem as ListViewItem and it always returns null no matter what I click. Do you maybe know how to get an entire row from that ListView?

Comment: Try to cast it into your ViewModelType

Comment: I cast it to DataRowView and accessed it with myItem.Row.ItemArray[<column id>].ToString() and got the values. Thank you for all the help.